# Where can I find a version of Xcode 3 that will run on Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: xcode, download, osx-leopard

I need to install Xcode 3 on my MacBook Pro (so I can install Haskell Platform).  I can't upgrade the MBP to Snow Leopard (10.6), but the Xcode 3 available for download from http://developer.apple.com/mac/ requires 10.6.  Is there a version of Xcode 3 that will work with Mac OS X 10.5.8?  Where do I find it?

My MacBook Pro was provided by my employer (which is why I can't upgrade to Snow Leopard), so I don't have access to the discs that came with it.

(Note, I moved this from https://superuser.com/questions/112629/where-can-i-find-a-version-of-xcode-3-that-will-run-on-mac-os-x-10-5/112630#112630 after noticing I had accidentally posted it there.)

Comment: Why did you move it? It seems the more appropriate place for it.

Comment: Since this is a question about developer tools, I thought it was more appropriate here.  (And I expect there will be more people with the experience to answer this question here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, the latest version which would work with 10.5.8 seems to be 3.1.4. It is really hard to find on the Apple site. After logging in, you may be able to access this page: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.3.3.3.1

Search for "3.1.4", or try this direct link: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.1.4_developer_tools/xcode314_2809_developerdvd.dmg

Answer (score 2):

You have to login to get to the link, so I don't think I can send you a direct link.
Does this work for you?
https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=19897

Answer (score 2):

It is tough to find on the site, but here's how:

1. go to http://developer.apple.com
2. Click "Resources" at the top of the page
3. Under OSX click "Downloads"
4. Uncheck all options but Developer Tools and type "XCode" into the search bar.  You will find all versions under this search.